# PoloniexTradeGUI trading application

Tags: security, poloniex

What features does PoloniexTradeGUI offer?

How does it secure login credentials?

Have any Monero core team members reviewed the code?

Comment: You mean https://github.com/swalecko/PoloniexTradeGUI right?

Comment: @onefox yes that is the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUI just offers an alternative way of trading on Poloniex. There are no additional features.

The password files are stores in plaintext in the same directory of the executable.

The code has not been audited by any core member and is not affiliated with the Monero project in any direct way.